# Same Pattern Apper Multiple Time Capture All Using gawk

Tags: regex, awk

Below is the String For Eg.,

```
[{"attrName":"val","difference":{"$numberDecimal":"-5900"},"diffPersent":{"$numberDecimal":"-4.4014"}},{"attrName":"totalTaxval","difference":{"$numberDecimal":"-5000.00"},"diffPersent":{"$numberDecimal":"-4.4014"}},{"attrName":"totalIamt","difference":{"$numberDecimal":"-900.00"}},{"attrName":"totalTaxAmt","difference":{"$numberDecimal":"-900.00"},"diffPersent":{"$numberDecimal":"-4.4014"}},{"attrName":"iamt","difference":{"$numberDecimal":"-900"},"index":0},{"attrName":"txval","difference":{"$numberDecimal":"-5000"},"index":0}]
```

Here I want all the Attribute after attrName.
Expected Result is below,

```
val,totalTaxval,totalIamt,totalTaxAmt,iamt,txval
```

I want to achieve this using gawk regex only, not any other language
Below is what i am trying but not working properly,

```
echo '[{"attrName":"val","difference":{"$numberDecimal":"-5900"},"diffPersent":{"$numberDecimal":"-4.4014"}},{"attrName":"totalTaxval","difference":{"$numberDecimal":"-5000.00"},"diffPersent":{"$numberDecimal":"-4.4014"}},{"attrName":"totalIamt","difference":{"$numberDecimal":"-900.00"}},{"attrName":"totalTaxAmt","difference":{"$numberDecimal":"-900.00"},"diffPersent":{"$numberDecimal":"-4.4014"}},{"attrName":"iamt","difference":{"$numberDecimal":"-900"},"index":0},{"attrName":"txval","difference":{"$numberDecimal":"-5000"},"index":0}]' | gawk '{match($0, /"attrName":"(.*)","/, ary); print ary[1];}'
```

Please help.

Comment: Why not use `jq`?

Comment: Try replacing the dot `.*` in your pattern with `[^"]*`. This will match anything not a double quote. Pattern: `/"attrName":"([^"]*)","/` Then your attrName value will be in your capture group.

Comment: I don't know the intricacies of GAWK but something like this seems to work `"attrName":"(.*?)"` per https://regexr.com/4julf

Comment: Hi dvo,

Your solution worked but its partial.
Its resulting only val in ary[1];ary[2] ary[3] all are empty..
Where are other attributes? see in given string attrName is present multiple times. I want all as comma separated..

Comment: Just to note, @MonkeyZeus, that the `*?` reluctant quantifier isn't supported by gawk. Still, your comment is excellent info for users of the many regex flavors that do support it.

Comment: @jas `"attrName":"([^"]*)"` is much better, but still it is pretty useless in gawk.

Comment: @jas, So what gawk solution for my query?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you mean (pretty) useless for parsing json as compared to using `jq`? If so, I totally agree.

Comment: If you must use gawk, I'm not sure you have a better option than calling `match` multiple times on successive substrings making use of `"start"` and `"length"`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html for details.

Comment: @jas, Thanks for suggestion. 
Keep everything where pattern match in input string, delete everything else.
If there is something like that then it will be helpful in gawk.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^"]*' '{o=s=""; for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if ($i=="attrName") {o=o s $(i+2); s=","} print o}' file
val,totalTaxval,totalIamt,totalTaxAmt,iamt,txval
```

Comment: This for loop is I have already written with me.
Doing this by loop is very time consuming.

I am processing some 100GB + data.

So expecting using regex or some one function but in awk only..

Thanks for the the help though.

Ideally regex should do this kind of stuff but awk regex is looks like not capable of doing this job. :(

Comment: This is using a regexp (the FPAT value) and no, it's not very time consuming. What makes you think using a single regexp across the whole record would be faster than using a loop?